# Insert inline image into Lotus Notes message

Tags: python, vba, lotus-notes

I've been able to send emails using Lotus Notes and VBA and Python using the COM API like this:

[Can I use Lotus Notes to send mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027400/can-i-use-lotus-notes-to-send-mail)

My question is how can I insert an image inline with the body text (not as an attachment) in a programmatic way (equivalent to the Edit | Paste Special)? I haven't been able to find any workable solutions from a few Google searches. Any solution using stock VBA or Python would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to do anything specific to Notes, i.e. work with a specific form with @functions etc, then you are much better off constructing the message as a multipart mime message.

You need to set up the session so that when you create the document it is mime and you can then set up your message appropriately, see `NotesSession.ConvertMIME`.  You will then use `NotesMIMEEntity` and `NotesMIMEHeader` objects to construct the mime message.

If you are unfamiliar with how mime messages are constructed then this is going to be a little tricky, so you may want to have a look at some raw mime messages to see what they look like.  From there you should be able to work out how to use the api for the `NotesMIMEEntity` and `NotesMIMEHeader` classes to construct the message.

Comment: This seems like the right path to me; although the API is complicated enough (even more so when trying to script it though straight COM with Python), I appreciate the push in the right direction. I'll post some code if I get it working.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to do this using the DXLImporter class, available from VBA through the COM interface. DXL is a Notes-specific XML, which you can generate to a temp file, then import into your database. There is sample code on this blog entry, which may be close to what you are looking for (this imports a rich-text body, including in-line image, and then attaches that rich text to a mail document).

http://www.cubetoon.com/2008/notes-rich-text-manipulation-using-dxl/

Other options you might consider are:

(1) using the C or C++ API's - definitely more effort, especially when working with rich-text, but would essentially have no limits. (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/capi-nd/index.html)

(2) using the MIDAS Toolkit from Genii (http://www.geniisoft.com) - extends the Lotuscript API's and exposes much of what is in the C API.