# Sending formatted Lotus Notes rich text email from Excel VBA

Tags: html, vba, lotus-notes

While trying to use the hints in your answer at

> [Sending formatted Lotus Notes rich text email from Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686384/sending-formatted-lotus-notes-rich-text-email-from-excel-vba)

I could do almost everything I needed: write multiple lines with data from a database of mine, formatting the body by mean of html code, with links and formatted text.

I also need to put an image in the mail body, but the html code "img src="etc. does not work, maybe because the image is located on my pc and is not reached by the recipients.
I need to find a way to embed the image just like I would do by mean of the Lotus menus.
In my Italian Lotus Notes 7, there is a Create menu with an Image option, I find the image, click OK and it is done.

That's what I wish to do with my code, please tell me it's possible! :-)

Thanks in advance.

Riccardo Baldinotti, Italy

Comment: See the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189622/insert-inline-image-into-lotus-notes-message

Answer (score 1):

At the address

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/DateAllThreadedweb/dcbf91b97004f0af8525773e002867a9?OpenDocument

I found a solution, and now my mail body has an image in it.

Here is my code.

```
Call stream.Open("<MY IMAGE PATH>")
Set body = MailDoc.CreateMIMEEntity '("memo")
Set richTextHeader = body.CreateHeader("Content-Type")
Call richTextHeader.SetHeaderVal("multipart/mixed")
Set mimeImage = body.CreateChildEntity()
strImageType = "image/jpeg" 'Other formats are "image/gif" "image/bmp"
Call mimeImage.SetContentFromBytes(stream, strImageType, ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY)
Call stream.Close
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://software.allfaq.org/forums/t/59865.aspx) you can find the complete code. It's too large to paste here, so I'm copying just a few lines to show the idea:

```
  If (bSetImages) Then
        For iImageIndex = 0 To Ubound(imageFilePaths)

              ' Get the image file path and content id (cid).
              strImagePath = Trim(imageFilePaths(iImageIndex))
              If (strImagePath = "") Then Exit Sub
              strImageCid = Trim(imageContentIds(iImageIndex))
              If (strImageCid = "") Then Exit Sub

              ' Get the image context type.
              If (StrContains(strImagePath, ".", True)) Then strImageExt = Strrightback(strImagePath, ".") Else strImageExt = ""
              Select Case Lcase(strImageExt)
              Case "gif":      strImageType = "image/gif"
              Case "jpg":      strImageType = "image/jpg"
              Case Else:      strImageType = "image/gif"
              End Select

              ' Add the image part.
              Set mimeImage = mimeBody.CreateChildEntity()
              Set mimeImageHeader = mimeImage.CreateHeader({Content-ID})
              Call mimeImageHeader.SetHeaderVal("<" & strImageCid & ">")
              Call stream.Open(strImagePath)
              Call mimeImage.SetContentFromBytes(stream, strImageType & {;name="} + strImageCid + {"}, ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY)
              Call stream.Close()

        Next
  End If
```

Comment: I can only add the image as an attachment. The code is in the next answer.